# Stuck on matrix derivative

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

I am stuck with this (probably simple) derivatives:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial X}Tr((A\odot(B^{T}XB))C)\;\;and \;\;\frac{\partial}{\partial X}Tr((A\odot(B^{T}XX^{T}B))C)
$$

where $A,B,C$ are constant matrices and $\odot$ is the Hadamard product.

Some help please?

Fabio

Answer (score 3):

The trace/Frobenius product is defined as
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(AB^T)$$
The cyclic property of the trace allows terms in such a product to be rearranged, e.g.
$$A:BC \;=\; AC^T:B \;=\; B^TA:C$$
The Frobenius and Hadamard products commute with themselves and each other.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A\odot B &= B\odot A \\
C:A\odot B &= C\odot A:B \\
}$$
Consider the following of function of the variable $Y$.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm Tr}\big((A\odot(B^TYB))C\big) \\
 &= (A\odot(B^TYB)):C^T \\
 &= (A\odot C^T):B^TYB \\
 &= B(A\odot C^T)B^T:Y \\
 &= M:Y \\
}$$
where $M,\,$ being a combination of constant matrices, 
is itself a constant matrix.

In the first case, set $Y=X\,$ then calculate the differential and the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi_1 &= M:X \\
d\phi_1 &= M:dX \\
\frac{\partial\phi_1}{\partial X} &= M \\
}$$
In the second case, set $Y=XX^T\,$ then
$$\eqalign{
\phi_2 &= M:XX^T \\
d\phi_2
 &= M:(dX\,X^T+X\,dX^T) \\
 &= (M+M^T):dX\,X^T \\
 &= (M+M^T)X:dX \\
\frac{\partial\phi_2}{\partial X} &= (M+M^T)X \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you Greg! Where can I find a nice book that explains in simple way how to use the formalism and rules you applied?

Comment: @Fabio I think greg would at least recommend "Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics" by Magnus and Neudecker. [I must admit that I have to read this book myself though]

Comment: Yes, Magnus and Neudecker is good;  I also like Hjorungnes's _"Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives"_; there's also an online PDF file titled _"The Matrix Cookbook"_ compiled by Petersen and Pedersen.

Comment: Great books thank you guys!